# Subscribe function is called more than once when reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I use subscribe function of knockout to get the selected value of the 1st dropdown to bind the value in the 2nd dropdown list. I store the selected dropdown values in session and change the value of the dropdown list while refreshing. At this time the subscribe is called twice as a result I get each value repeated in the dropdown.

```
   self.getcountry = function () {         
        try {
     //code               
            $.ajax({
                //code
                statusCode: {
                    200: function (response) {                                   
                        $.each(response, function (index, data) {
                            self.country.push(data);
                        })
                        if(SESSIONVALUES!=null)
                        {
                             for (var i = 0; i < SESSIONVALUES.length; i++) {
                                var COUNTRYbind=SESSIONVALUES[i].vCOUNTRY;                           

                                $('#country option').filter(function () { return $.trim($(this).val()) == parseInt( COUNTRYbind); }).attr('selected', true);
                                $('#country ').change();                                 
                                self.selectedCountry(COUNTRYbind);// this is used to trigger the subscribe function       

                                                                }


                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (exception) { }
    };
```

This is the subscribe function method,

```
  self.selectedCountry.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        //code
        try {

            $.ajax({
               //code
                statusCode: {
                    200: function (response) {                           
                        $.each(response, function (index, data) {
                            self.state.push(data);
                        })
                        if(SESSIONVALUES!=null)
                        {
                            for (var i = 0; i < SESSIONVALUES.length; i++) {                       
                                var statebind=SESSIONVALUES[i].vstate;
                                $('#states option').filter(function () { return $.trim($(this).val()) == parseInt(statebind); }).attr('selected', true);
                                $('#states').change();

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            });
        } catch (Exception) { }

    });
```

Comment: You should be using your viewmodel to set the options.

Comment: I am pretty sure that  $('#country ').change() and self.selectedCountry(COUNTRYbind); will both trigger your subscription event. (Not 100% i have not touched knockout for a while)

Answer (score 3):

I came across this exact issue an hour ago!

Try this:

```
ko.subscribable.fn.subscribeChanged = function (callback) {
    var oldValue;
    this.subscribe(function (_oldValue) {
        oldValue = _oldValue;
    }, this, 'beforeChange');

    this.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        callback(newValue, oldValue);
    });
};
```

Then you can subscribe and when it's triggered you can compare the oldValue with the newValue.

e.g. in your ViewModel

```
self.selectedCountry.subscribeChanged(function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue != oldValue) // Value has changed.
    {
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: what values will be passed in the oldvalue and newvalue? can u kindly expalin me the flow?

Comment: The newValue is the same value as in your example.  The oldValue is the previous value.  There is a chance that although it's triggering twice, if the value hasn't changed(e.g. when newValue == oldValue) then you can safely ignore it.  Chances are the first time it triggers newValue != oldValue, and the second time it triggers newValue == oldValue.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery code you're using does not belong there. Your code should only be altering viewmodel elements, and Knockout will make the DOM reflect the viewmodel. Then you won't have to hack on `subscribable` and turn your code into some sort of unsupportable mishmash. Use Knockout.

[This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643130/knockoutjs-dependent-select-boxes-problems-binding-child-select-box) may give you an idea of how to set up your dependent select lists.

Answer (score 0):

Just add "return false;" at the end of function;