# How to achieve cascade dropdown functionality for List using KnockoutJs

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

HTML:

```
 <div>
    <div id="filter-drop-down" tabindex="1">
        <span data-bind="text:selected_Auth()"></span>
        <ul class="dropdown" data-bind="foreach:selectList">
            <li><a href="#" data-bind="text:name.toLowerCase(),click:$parent.addToRightList,css:{'selected-filter':$parent.selected_Auth==name}"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="filter-drop-down1" data-bind="with:rightList" tabindex="1">
        <span data-bind="text:selected_Book.toLowerCase()"></span>
        <ul class="dropdown" data-bind="foreach:selectList">
            <li><a href="#" data-bind="text:DscName.toLowerCase(),click:$parent.selected_Book.bind($root,DscName),css:{'selected-filter':$root.selected_Book()==DscName}"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function view_model() {
  var self = this;
  self.all_consultants = ko.observableArray();
  self.selected_Auth = ko.observable("all Author");
  self.selected_Book = ko.observable("all books");
  self.selectList = ko.observableArray([{
    name: "J.K R",
    DscName: [
      "HP1", "HP2", "HP3"
    ]
  }, {
    name: "shakespeare",
    DscName: [
      "Hamlet", "Othello"
    ]
  }]);

  //if (self.auth_header()) {
  //  get_list_data();
  //}

  self.rightList = ko.observable();
  self.addToRightList = function(list) {
    self.rightList(list);
  };

}
ko.applyBindings(new view_model());
```

Need Dropdown like functionality On 1st list Author selection populate 2 list with Books and if there is only 1 book then it should be autoselected.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643130/knockoutjs-dependent-select-boxes-problems-binding-child-select-box

Comment: Also http://learn.knockoutjs.com/

Comment: Hi Roy I tried with Select it is working but not able to bind when it comes to List...

Comment: Can you post the code that works for a Select?

Comment: self.selVDF = ko.observableArray([new SelectMyBook()]);
function SelectMyBook() {
    var self = this;
    self.selectedBook = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.selectedAuth = ko.observable();
    self.selectedAuth.subscribe(function () {
    self.selectedBook(undefined);
    },self);
}
<tbody data-bind="foreach: selVDF">
 <tr>
  <td><select data-bind="options: $root.selectList, value: selectedAuth, optionsText: 'name'"></select></td>
  <td><select data-bind="options: selectedAuth, value: selectedBook, optionsText: 'DscName'"></select></td>
 </tr>
</tbody>

Comment: You won't be able to post your code as a comment. Edit your original post.

Comment: Roy you understand my issue right? try for cascading behavior in list.
I am new to knockout but not finding proper help..

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have not gotten much help with your question is that it came across as "write some code for me" rather than "I am trying to do this and running into a particular problem." StackOverflow is about helping you understand things, not just putting up some code to have other people make it work.

The code you presented had many errors. I edited your question to get rid of the syntax errors so that it at least could run. Below I have worked out some of the problems to make the dependency you were looking for.

Some things to note:

- You cannot use `toLowerCase` directly on an observable, you have to get at its contents, so it's `selected_Book().toLowerCase()`, not `selected_Book.toLowerCase()`
- You must pay attention to binding contexts. `rightList` does not contain a `selectList` member; it has a `DscName`, which is what should be used in the 2nd `foreach`. Binding contexts are the reason I had to put `$root` on a number of things.
- When you have a problem like this with multiple requirements, break it down. Maybe the first thing you should have worked out was how to successfully display two lists. Then work on building the second list from the first.

```js
function view_model() {
  var self = this;
  self.all_consultants = ko.observableArray();
  self.selected_Auth = ko.observable("all Author");
  self.selected_Book = ko.observable("all books");
  self.selectList = ko.observableArray([{
    name: "J.K R",
    DscName: [
      "HP1", "HP2", "HP3"
    ]
  }, {
    name: "shakespeare",
    DscName: [
      "Hamlet", "Othello"
    ]
  }]);

  //if (self.auth_header()) {
  //  get_list_data();
  //}

  self.rightList = ko.observable();
  self.addToRightList = function(list) {
    self.rightList(list);
  };

}
ko.applyBindings(new view_model());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div id="filter-drop-down" tabindex="1">
        <span data-bind="text:selected_Auth()"></span>
        <ul class="dropdown" data-bind="foreach:selectList">
            <li><a href="#" data-bind="text:name.toLowerCase(),
              click:$parent.addToRightList,
              css:{'selected-filter':$parent.selected_Auth==name}"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="filter-drop-down1" tabindex="1" data-bind="with: rightList">
        <span data-bind="text:$root.selected_Book().toLowerCase()"></span>
        <ul class="dropdown" data-bind="foreach:DscName">
            <li><a href="#" data-bind="text:$data.toLowerCase(),
              click:$root.selected_Book.bind($root,$data),
              css:{'selected-filter':$root.selected_Book()==$data}"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```